# calling jquery function for toastr notification

Tags: javascript, jquery, toastr

I want notifications from toastr to pop up when these links are clicked but nothing happens

EDIT: here is the jsfiddle of the full code http://jsfiddle.net/XaVcR/  I'm not sure if I included toastr properly though 
    
    Success
     
.js

```
toastr.options.closeButton = true;
toastr.options.positionClass = "toast-bottom-left";

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#success').click(notification('success', 'this was a success!'));
});

function notification( type, message ) {
if( type == 'success' ) {
    toastr.success(message,'<i>Success</i>');
} else if( type == 'error' ) {
    toastr.error(message,'Error');
} else if( type == 'warning' ) {
    toastr.warning(message,'Warning');
} else {
    toastr.info(message,'Information');
}   
}
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? Can you show the *entire* code? Or a reproduction in, e.g. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XaVcR/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the question:

```
    $('#success').click(notification('success', 'this was a success!'));
```

This should be:

```
$('#success').click(function() {
    notification('success', 'this was a success!');
});
```

Your JSFiddle has:

```
$('#success').click(function() {
    notification('success', 'this was a success!'));
});
```

which, with the `))` at the end of the middle line, is a syntax error.